# No consigo implementar listas en c++

Tags: c++, linux, estructuras-de-datos, punteros, estructuras

Resumen: Estoy intentando implementar listas en un programa con los métodos de añadir y mostrar por pantalla.

problema: En relativa medida el programa funciona bien no reporta ningún error pero a la hora de mostrar el los elementos añadidos no muestra absolutamente nada.

La función `system("clear")` es una función general dentro de posix es decir linux para que en windows no reporte ningún error "clear" ha de ser sustituido por "cls" para que funcione con windows.

Informacion extra: trabajo en en Arch Linux x86_64 con el kernel version 5.8.1-zen1-1-zen en sublime-text-3

Nota del autor: He comentado todo el código especificando que he hecho, porque lo he hecho y para que lo he hecho. Soy nuevo en la comunidad no pretendo que hagan mi trabajo simplemente no he hallado manera de solventar el error tras corregir y rehacer el proyecto varias veces y tampoco se de alguien que pudiese ser de ayuda, gracias por la compresión.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

//declaracion de la estructura de datos

struct nodo{
    int dato;
    nodo *siguiente;
};

//clase donde se va almacenar los metodos y los elementos de la lista

class listas{
    nodo *elemento;
public:
    listas();
    void agregar(nodo cima);
    void mostrar();
};

//main donde hay un menu que te deja seleccionar si quieres
//añadir o mostrar elementos por pantalla llamando a los metodos de
//la clase "listas"

int main(){
    //variable para selecionar una de las dos opciones
    int opcion;
    char opcion_;
    opcion_ = 'y';
    //declaracion de la variable que se le va a pasar por parametro
    nodo referencia;
    //se iguala el puntero siguiente de referencia a NULL asi el primer elemento
    //de la lista no apuntara a ningun elemento porque no hay otro 
    referencia.siguiente = NULL;
    //declaracion del objeto de la clase listas para llamar a las funciones
    // dentro del main
    listas objeto;
    //menu
    cout << "--- Menu Listas ---" << endl
         << " 1- agregar" << endl
         << " 2- mostrar" << endl;
         cin >> opcion;
         switch(opcion){
            //se llama a la funcion añadir
            case 1:
            //el bucle se repetira hasta que no introduzca otra opcion que no sea 
            // 'y' o 'Y'
                while((opcion_ == 'y') || (opcion_ == 'Y')){
                    system("clear");
                    cout << "introduce el dato: ";
                    cin >> referencia.dato;
                    objeto.agregar(referencia);
                    cout  << "quiere añadir otro elemento(Y/N)...";
                    cin >>opcion_;
                }
                
                system("clear");
                return main();
            break;
            case 2: 
                system("clear");
                objeto.mostrar();
                system("clear");
                return main();
            break;
            //si la opcion introducida por teclado no es valida devolvera al menu principal
            //tras limpiar pantalla
            default:
                cout << "introduce una opcion valida";
                system("clear");
                return main();
         }

}
//el constructor de la lista no hace nada

listas::listas(){

}

//agrega un elemento al principio de la lista al ser llamada
//se crea un espacio en memoria se rellena con el dato que pasamos 
//por teclado e siguiente del elemento pasa a ser el miembro
//de cima "siguiente" el cual como le he pasado por referencia
//"referencia" en el caso del primer elemento deberia ser nulo
//y luego cima como su nombre indica debe de estar en la cima 
//por ende la igualo a elemento el cual por ser el que va a ser
//añadido como nuevo siempre va a estar en la cima

void listas::agregar(nodo cima){
    elemento = new nodo();
    elemento -> dato = cima.dato;
    elemento -> siguiente = cima.siguiente;
    cima = *elemento;
}

//declaro la variable dato que va a contener los datos que 
//introducimos por teclado a la lista luego añado un bucle 
//que se va repetir hasta que no siguiente sea igual a NULL
//y como el unico puntero siguiente de los elementos que apunta
//a NULL es el primero que se añadio por ende el ultimo de la lista
//el bucle solo termina una vez llega al final de la lista
//y lo que hace es copiar cada uno de los datos que hay contenidos 
//dentro del miembro de aux "dato" dentro de una variable de tipo entero
//llamada dato_ y luego pasa al siguiente elemento de la lista
//luego imprime por pantalla dato_ 

void listas::mostrar(){
    int dato_;
    nodo *aux = elemento;
    while(aux -> siguiente != NULL){
        dato_ = aux -> dato;
        aux = aux -> siguiente;
    }
    cout << dato_ << ", ";
}
```

Muchas gracias por la atención, siento posibles molestias ocasionadas y acepto sugerencias y criticas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a la hora de mostrar el los elementos añadidos no muestra absolutamente nada.

Eso es porque la función que añade elementos a la lista no funciona correctamente

```
void listas::agregar(nodo cima){
    elemento = new nodo();
    elemento -> dato = cima.dato;
    elemento -> siguiente = cima.siguiente;
    cima = *elemento;
}
```

`elemento` es el puntero de la lista... así que cada vez que añades un nodo nuevo sobreescribes su valor... perdiendo el nodo anterior. Por cierto, nota que la última instrucción de esa función no hace **absolutamente nada**. `cima` es una variable local de la función, es decir, cuando el programa abandone la función la variable desaparecerá. Luego esa asignacion solo sirve para consumir ciclos de reloj.

Además, los nodos no deberían estar tan expuestos, los nodos son una parte estructural de la lista y, por tanto, deberían estar gestionados de forma interna por la propia lista.

Para añadir elementos deberías hacer algo tal que:

```
void listas::agregar(int valor)
{
    nodo * nuevo = new nodo;
    nuevo->dato = nuevo;
    nuevo->siguiente = elemento;

    elemento = nuevo;
}
```

Nota que en este caso los nuevos elementos se añaden al inicio de la lista. Con la lógica que tienes puesta no queda claro cómo debe comportarse la lista. También se podrían añadir los elementos al final de la lista... simplemente habría que recorrer la lista para localizar el último nodo y añadir a continuación el nuevo elemento.

Por cierto, fíjate que la función `mostrar` solo es capaz de mostrarte dos posibles valores:

- El penúltimo nodo
- Basura

El bucle `while`, que es el que recorre la lista, **no imprime nada**, luego la colección se recorre de forma silenciosa. El último elemento no se itera, ya que en ese caso `dato->siguiente == NULL`, luego en `dato_`, que solo se imprimirá una vez, se encontrará el valor del penúltimo nodo. Si no hay penúltimo entonces se imprimirá basura ya que `dato_` no está inicializado:

```
void listas::mostrar(){
    int dato_;
    nodo *aux = elemento;
    while(aux -> siguiente != NULL){
        dato_ = aux -> dato;
        aux = aux -> siguiente;
    }
    cout << dato_ << ", ";
}
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es, entre otras cosas, poner el `cout` dentro del bucle:

```
void listas::mostrar(){
    nodo *aux = elemento;
    while(aux != nullptr){
        std::cout << aux->dato << ", ";
        aux = aux->siguiente;
    }
}
```